# Displaying a Single Data from SQLite using Getters and Setters

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve and display a single row from my database to an activity. I was wondering if I can use the Getters and Setters in order to pass the value around. I was able to retrieve the data easily but the problem is it seems that I'm having problem with passing the values using getters and setter. Here's what I've been getting at LogCat.

```
09-22 13:46:33.573: D/Enter Activity(3110): You have entered Score Activity
09-22 13:46:34.177: D/Data Retreival(3110): Getting Data
09-22 13:46:34.183: D/User(3110): 1 XyLoL 0 0 null null
09-22 13:46:34.183: D/Database(3110): Database Close
09-22 13:46:34.194: D/USER INFO(3110): 0 null 0 0 null null
09-22 13:46:34.194: W/ResourceType(3110): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
09-22 13:46:34.203: D/AndroidRuntime(3110): Shutting down VM
09-22 13:46:34.203: W/dalvikvm(3110): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
09-22 13:46:34.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 13:46:34.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xylol.o_chabeta/com.xylol.o_chabeta.Enter_Score}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

I just want to ask if it

User_Score.java(Activity)

```
public class Enter_Score extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ScoreDataSource datasource;
    UserHandler user;

    //Textview Declaration

    TextView username;
    TextView score;
    TextView questions_left;
    TextView best_cat;
    TextView worst_cat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter__score);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats_username);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stat_score);
        questions_left = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stat_questions_left);
        best_cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats_best);
        worst_cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats_worst);

        datasource = new ScoreDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        Log.d("Data Retreival", "Getting Data");
        datasource.getScore();
        datasource.close();


        UserHandler user = new UserHandler();

        long user_id = user.getUSER_ID();
        String user_n =user.getUSER_NAME();
        int user_s =user.getUSER_SCORE();
        int user_ql= user.getUSER_QUESTIONS_LEFT();
        String user_b = user.getUSER_BEST_CATEGORY() ;
        String user_w =  user.getUSER_WORST_CATEGORY();

        Log.d("USER INFO", user_id+ " " + user_n + " " + user_s + " " + user_ql + " " + user_b + " " + user_w);

        username.setText(user_n);
        score.setText(user_s);
        questions_left.setText(user_ql);
        best_cat.setText(user_b);
        worst_cat.setText(user_w);


        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.enter__score, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.back){
            Intent i = new Intent(Enter_Score.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    }



}
```

ScoreDataSource.java(Data Retrival)

```
public class ScoreDataSource extends Enter_Score{


    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;


    private static final String[] allColumns = {
        O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_ID,
        O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_NAME,
        O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_SCORE,
        O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_QUESTIONS_LEFT,
        O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_BEST_CATEGORY,
        O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_WORST_CATEGORY
    };

    public ScoreDataSource(Context context){

        dbhelper = new O_chaDBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() {
        database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        Log.d("Database", "Database Close");
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public void getScore() {

        Cursor c = database.query(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_TABLE, allColumns, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();

        int iid = c.getColumnIndex(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_ID);
        int iusername = c.getColumnIndex(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_NAME);
        int iscore = c.getColumnIndex(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_SCORE);
        int iql = c.getColumnIndex(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_QUESTIONS_LEFT);
        int ibc = c.getColumnIndex(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_BEST_CATEGORY);
        int iwc = c.getColumnIndex(O_chaDBOpenHelper.USER_WORST_CATEGORY);

        // Get and Set Valueszzz

        long id = c.getLong(iid);
        String username = c.getString(iusername);
        int score = c.getInt(iscore);
        int questions_left = c.getInt(iql);
        String best_cat = c.getString(ibc);
        String worst_cat = c.getString(iwc);

        Log.d("User", id+ " " + username+  " " + score+ " " + questions_left + " " + best_cat + " " + worst_cat );

        UserHandler user = new UserHandler();

        user.setUSER_ID(id);
        user.setUSER_NAME(username);
        user.setUSER_SCORE(score);
        user.setUSER_QUESTIONS_LEFT(questions_left);
        user.setUSER_BEST_CATEGORY(best_cat);
        user.setUSER_WORST_CATEGORY(worst_cat);


    }

}
```

UserHandler.java (Getters and Setter)

```
public class UserHandler {

    private long USER_ID;
    private String USER_NAME;
    private int USER_SCORE;
    private int USER_QUESTIONS_LEFT;
    private String USER_BEST_CATEGORY;
    private String USER_WORST_CATEGORY;

    public UserHandler(){

    }

    public UserHandler(int ID, String NAME, String GENDER, String COUNTRY, int SCORE, int QUESTION_LEFT, String BEST_CATEGORY, String WORST_CATEGORY){
        this.USER_ID = ID;
        this.USER_NAME = NAME;
        this.USER_SCORE = SCORE;
        this.USER_QUESTIONS_LEFT = QUESTION_LEFT;
        this.USER_BEST_CATEGORY = BEST_CATEGORY;
        this.USER_WORST_CATEGORY = WORST_CATEGORY;
    }

    public long getUSER_ID() {
        return USER_ID;
    }

    public void setUSER_ID(long uSER_ID) {
        this.USER_ID = uSER_ID;
    }

    public String getUSER_NAME() {
        return USER_NAME;
    }

    public void setUSER_NAME(String uSER_NAME) {
        this.USER_NAME = uSER_NAME;
    }

    public int getUSER_SCORE() {
        return USER_SCORE;
    }

    public void setUSER_SCORE(int uSER_SCORE) {
        this.USER_SCORE = uSER_SCORE;
    }

    public int getUSER_QUESTIONS_LEFT() {
        return USER_QUESTIONS_LEFT;
    }

    public void setUSER_QUESTIONS_LEFT(int uSER_QUESTIONS_LEFT) {
        this.USER_QUESTIONS_LEFT = uSER_QUESTIONS_LEFT;
    }

    public String getUSER_BEST_CATEGORY() {
        return USER_BEST_CATEGORY;
    }

    public void setUSER_BEST_CATEGORY(String uSER_BEST_CATEGORY) {
        this.USER_BEST_CATEGORY = uSER_BEST_CATEGORY;
    }

    public String getUSER_WORST_CATEGORY() {
        return USER_WORST_CATEGORY;
    }

    public void setUSER_WORST_CATEGORY(String uSER_WORST_CATEGORY) {
        this.USER_WORST_CATEGORY = uSER_WORST_CATEGORY;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object of UserHandler you created in User_Score.java and ScoreDataSource.java are different. Hence you didn't get the correct value.

May be you can create UserHandler class Singleton.

Comment: @John : if you are asking about singleton, just google it and you will get many useful links.

Comment: @JohnMichaelJames : I would like to bring into notice that if your question is get resolved completely, then ONLY mark it as accepted.